# React-slick slider test case error - cannot read property 'querySelectorAll'

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, next.js, react-slick

I am using [next.js](https://nextjs.org/) for React project and used [react-slick](https://react-slick.neostack.com/) slider plugin it's working properly but when I try to run test it through - `TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null.

For test setup I used [this](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/blob/master/test-setup.js) configuration.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null

  16 | 
  17 |   it('render with error param', () => {
> 18 |     const tree: ReactTestRendererJSON = renderer.create(
     |                                                  ^
  19 |       <Home />
  20 |     ).toJSON();
  21 |   });
```

Searched a lot but didn't get any solution.

Comment: Facing same issue in gatsby.js  test. I also couldn't found what's wrong. 

Comment: any updates on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is a latest bug, try using

```
"react-slick": "^0.25.0",
```

It worked for me in gatsby.js

Here is the reported issue: https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/issues/1830